# Refactor the code to avoid the goto statement

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

What is the best way to avoid the goto statement in my C# code?
I want to get rid of the goto statement to restart the execution of the for loop

```
//some processing statements
//..
//..

start:
var rowCollection = GetData();
int RowCount = rowCollection.Count;
for(int iRow = 0; iRow < RowCount; iRow++)
{

  if(rowCollection[iRow]["Col"] > 0)
  {
     goto start;
  }

  else
  {
     //some processing statement
  }
}

//some more processing statements
//..
//..
```

where,

1. RowCount = number of rows received from GetData() method
2. rowCollection[iRow]["Col"], "Col" is some column name

Comment: In order to answer this properly, we need to know what your code is supposed to do.

Comment: `int iRow`...`iRow["Col"]`...this doesn't make sense.

Comment: "Col" is some column name. The above snippet is just a psuedocode

Comment: No, pseudo code conveys something, and indexing an integer is nonsense. Pseudo code simplifies to focus on a point (and is hence no good for a question about refactoring out a language feature anyway). That bit confuses, not simplifies. We can't figure out what needs to be redone where the `goto` currently is because of this.

Comment: @JonHanna You've seen the light. :)

Comment: @JonHanna : My bad, have corrected it in my pseudocode

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you have to refactor your code to make it clearer, for example something like this:

```
bool result;
do
{
    var rowCollection = GetData();
    result = ProcessData(rowCollection);
} while (!result);
```

And then have this method:

```
bool ProcessData(RowCollection rowCollection)
{
    foreach (var item in rowCollection)
    {
        if (item["Col"] > 0)
        {
            return false;
        }
        else
        {
            // Do your stuff.
        }
    }

    return true;
}
```

This way your code is much more readable and maintainable.

Comment: Thank you, amongst other answers. This one is much more readable

Answer (score 0):

```
var rowCollection = GetData();

for(int iRow = 0; iRow < RowCount; iRow++)
{
    if(iRow["Col"] > 0)
    {
        rowCollection = GetData();
        RowCount=rowCollection.length();
        irow = 0;
    }
    else
    {
        //some processing statement
    }
}
```

Comment: This *might* work, if you've correctly guessed the OP's intent.

Comment: Have in mind that `irow != iRow`.

Comment: I would assume irow is iRow

Answer (score -1):

Not very sure what your use case is, but you can do this.

```
var rowCollection = GetData();

for(int iRow = 0; iRow < RowCount; iRow++)
{
    if(iRow["Col"] > 0)
    {
        rowCollection = GetData();
        irow = 0;
    }
    else
    {
        //some processing statement
    }
}
```

Comment: Down voter, please include comment. It helps understanding the case.

Comment: I don't see how posting code without understanding the OP's intent is going to help anyone.

Comment: I did, this what OP says _"What is the best way to avoid the goto statement in my C# code? I want to get rid of the goto statement to restart the execution of the for loop "_

Comment: You asked, I answered.

Comment: Do you explain why this is not the answer to question?

Comment: You see, this is why I don't usually explain my downvotes.  Every time I do someone the courtesy, I wind up in an argument.

Comment: I don't see it as an argument, I learn If I'm doing something really wrong.

Comment: Have in mind that `irow != iRow`. `RowCount` is not updated either. And the code ends up quite obscure.

Comment: Sorry guys, I guess I should have included detailed pseudocode.